# If an autocorrelation function of a process is a rectangular function, then is the process deterministic?

Tags: autocorrelation

I would like to clarify one doubt regarding autocorrelation function $R_x (\tau)$ of a process $X(t)$. Suppose $R_x (\tau) = \Pi (\tau)$, where $\Pi (\tau)$ is the rectangular function. Then is the process $X(t)$ deterministic.

Comment: Why do you think it would be deterministic?

Comment: A friend of mine told that this autocorrelation cannot hold true for a random process. So I was thinking that it would be deterministic.

Comment: As Jazzmaniac's answer implies, the rectangular pulse cannot be the autocorrelation function of _anything_, random process or deterministic signal or whatever. Your friend's statement is correct but incomplete and you are choosing an inapporpriate negation. "OK, the rectangular pulse is not the autocorelation of a random process and so the process must be deterministic"  **Not so.** The rectangular pulse is not the autocorrelation of any process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An autocorrelation function like that is not possible for ordinary signals. The autocorrelation function is the Fourier transform of the power spectral density, which is a strictly positive quantity. However, to get a rectangular function as Fourier transform you need to have negative values. That is in conflict with the strictly positive power spectrum.